# To check if an object is empty or not

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, collections, flex3

I want to check in my function if a passed argument of type object is empty or not. Sometimes it is empty but still not null thus I can not rely on null condition. Is there some property like 'length'/'size' for flex objects which I can use here.
Please help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I retagged your question with collections. You question is a bit vague, maybe you can clearify it to get more/better answers.
Are using an Object instance as an associative array? If you need a count, maybe you use the Array class instead.
If you describe the context a bit better it will be easier to answer.

Comment: If you use an associative array, you get exactly the same thing as an object. The length property will always return 0 no matter how make keys you fill.

Comment: I meant not using a and associative array, but changing the code to use a normal array. An associative array indicates that you know which values are stored, and therefor you would not normally need to count the. But it is hard to say without more detail.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you mean if an Object has no properties:

```
var isEmpty:Boolean = true;
for (var n in obj) { isEmpty = false; break; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it was really useful but still can't we have some builtin method like :
"myObj.length"/'myObj.isEmpty' 

Thanks again.

Comment: You are gonna have to extend the `Object` class or the `Dictionary` class to get an "inbuilt" method for that :)

Comment: There is monkeypatching, but that breaks for .. in loops, which... well... you know.

Comment: @Bob: `ObjectUtils` is not a standard API, but yes it would be preferable to patching `Object`. It is actually possible to have a top-level function (put `package foo { public function bar() { ... } }` in a file `foo/bar.as`), which I stylistically prefer to `FooUtils` classes.

Comment: What do you mean by non-standard?  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/ObjectUtil.html

Comment: @Bob: Ahh, I was looking for ObjectUtil*s*.

Comment: Wow sorry, didn't catch that!

Answer (score 6):

This is some serious hack but you can use:

```
Object.prototype.isEmpty = function():Boolean {
    for(var i in this)
        if(i != "isEmpty")
            return false
    return true
}

var p = {};
trace(p.isEmpty()); // true
var p2 = {a:1}
trace(p2.isEmpty()); // false
```

Comment: wow, that's an interesting trick.  You just sent me on a quest to learn about the prototype member.  Not sure how I might use it, but it's an interesting bit of guts to know about.

Comment: I try to avoid prototypes, because the flex compiler complains alot. And I must admit that I'm an auto-completion addict...

Comment: possibly check using `this.hasOwnProperty(i)`, in case of other prototype members.

Answer (score 5):

You can also try:

```
ObjectUtil.getClassInfo(obj).properties.length > 0
```

The good thing about it is that getClassInfo gives you much more info about the object, eg. you get the names of all the properties in the object, which might come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

If object containes some 'text' but as3 doesn't recognize it as a String, convert it to string and check if it's empty.

```
var checkObject:String = myObject;

if(checkObject == '')
{
  trace('object is empty');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what your object is, or rather what you expect it to have.  For example if your object is supposed to contain some property called name that you are looking for, you might do

```
if(objSomeItem == null || objSomeItem.name == null || objSomeItem.name.length == 0)
{
 trace("object is empty");
}
```

or if your object is actually supposed to be something else, like an array you could do

```
var arySomeItems = objSomeItem as Array;
if(objSomeItem == null || arySomeItems == null || arySomeItems.length == 0)
{
  trace("object is empty");
}
```

You could also use other ways through reflection, such as ObjectUtil.getClassInfo, then enumerate through the properties to check for set values....  this class help:

```
import flash.utils.describeType;
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

public class ReflectionUtils 
{
    /** Returns an Array of All Properties of the supplied object */
    public static function GetVariableNames(objItem:Object):Array
    {
        var xmlPropsList:XMLList = describeType(objItem)..variable;
        var aryVariables:Array = new Array();
        if (xmlPropsList != null)
        {
            for (var i:int; i < xmlPropsList.length(); i++)
            {
                aryVariables.push(xmlPropsList[i].@name);
            }
        }

        return aryVariables;
    }

    /** Returns the Strongly Typed class of the specified library item */
    public static function GetClassByName($sLinkageName:String):Class
    {
        var tObject:Class = getDefinitionByName($sLinkageName) as Class;
        return tObject;
    }

    /** Constructs an instance of the speicified library item */
    public static function ConstructClassByName($sLinkageName:String):Object
    {
        var tObject:Class = GetClassByName($sLinkageName);
        //trace("Found Class: " + tMCDefinition);
        var objItem:* = new tObject();
        return objItem;
    }

    public static function DumpObject(sItemName:String, objItem:Object):void
    {
        trace("*********** Object Dump: " + sItemName + " ***************");
        for (var sKey:String in objItem)
        {
            trace("    " + sKey +": " + objItem[sKey]);
        }
    }
    //}
}
```

Another thing to note is you can use a simple for loop to check through an objects properties, thats what this dumpobject function is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly check it as follow,

```
var obj:Object = new Object();
if(obj == null)
{
//Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I stole this from a similar question relating to JS. It requires FP 11+ or a JSON.as library.

```
function isEmptyObject(obj){
    return JSON.stringify(obj) === '{}';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

can use use the hasProperty method to check for length

```
var i:int = myObject.hasProperty("length") ? myObject.length: 0;
```

Comment: His problem is that there's no length field on dynamic objects.

Comment: The way I read it is that he did not know if there were a length property or not.